# How can I sort table output when the query is dependent on a $_GET with only PHP?

Tags: php, html, sql

I have a Website which presents the tools from one table and the corresponding ratings from another table within on page calles f_toolseite.php. I would like for the user to be able to sort the ratings according to best rating and worst ratings. however, since I am using only php the info which tool is being looked at is getting deleted when i press the button to sort the ratings. What I mean by that is that the $_GET variables im using to get to the tool and ratings the user wishes to see are being deleted from the adress bar.
Ive tought of implementing sessions but i cant get it to work. is there any way i can solve this problem with php only?

here is my code
for f_toolseite.php
'''

```
<html>
    <head>
       

<center>
<div class="tool-container">
    
    <?php 
    
    $name = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_GET['name']);

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM Tools WHERE t_name = '$name' "; 
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);  
    $queryResults = mysqli_num_rows($result); 
    
    if($queryResults > 0 ){
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
                
    ##      $image = base64_encode($row['t_bild']);
        ##   echo "
        ##   <img src=data:image/png;base64,'$image'>";
             
        
            echo " <div class='tool-box'>  
            <img src=".$row['t_logo']. " width= 200>
            <h3> ".$row['t_kategorie']."</h3>
            <br>
            <img src=".$row['t_bild']. " width= 800>
            <br>
            <br>
            <p>".$row['t_beschreibung']."<p>
            <br>
            <p><b>Probier's doch gleich aus!</b></p>
            <a href=".$row['t_link']."> ".$row['t_link']."</a> 
        </div>"; 
            
        }
    }
    
    
    
    ?>
    
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    
<div class="avg-container">
    <?php
    
    $id = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_GET['id']);
    
    $sql3 = "SELECT ROUND (AVG (b_nivg)) AS average FROM Bewertungen WHERE t_id = '$id'";
    $result3 = mysqli_query($conn, $sql3);  
    $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result3);
    $average = $row['average'];
            echo ("ALLES IN ALLEM EINE $average VON 10 ");
    
    $sql4 = "SELECT  b_industrie 
    COUNT(b_industrie) AS oft
    FROM  Bewertungen WHERE t_id = '$id'
    GROUP BY b_industrie
    ORDER BY oft DESC
    LIMIT    1";
    $result4 = mysqli_query($conn, $sql4);  
    $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result4);
    $industry = $row['oft'];
            echo ("Am beliebtesten in der $industry Industrie ");
    
    
    ?>
    
    
</div>  
    
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    
    
    <div class="filter-container">
    
    <form action="f_toolseite.php" method="post">
      <select name="sort">
         <option value="" selected="selected">Nach den neusten Bewertungen geordnet</option>
         <option value="b_nivg ASC">Am besten bewertet</option>
         <option value="b_nivg DESC">Am schlechtesten bewertet</option>
      </select>
      <input name="search" type="submit" value="Ordnen"/>
   </form>
   
   <?php
      if(isset($_POST['sort'])) {
         $sort = $_POST['sort'];
      }
         
    ?>
         
    </div>
    
<div class="rate-container">
    <?php
    
    
    $id = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_GET['id']);
    
    
     if(!empty($sort)){
        $sql2 = "SELECT * FROM Bewertungen WHERE t_id = '$id' ORDER BY b_datum DESC,'$sort'";
     }
     else{
        $sql2 = "SELECT * FROM Bewertungen WHERE t_id = '$id' ORDER BY b_datum DESC";
     }
    
    $result2 = mysqli_query($conn, $sql2);  
    $queryResults2 = mysqli_num_rows($result2); 
    $crown= "https://project-disti.wbs.hs-rm.de/learn/ss2021/workspace/dbmgruppe2/Collatio%20(22.06.2021)/img/Webtool-Bilder/crown_PNG16.png";
    
    
    if($queryResults2 > 0 ){
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result2)){
            echo " <div class='rating-box'> 
            <p>".$row['b_vorname']." ".$row['b_nachname']."</p>
            <br>
            <p>".$row['b_industrie']."</p>
            <p>".$row['b_dauer']."<p>
            <p>".$row['b_niveau']."<p>
            ".( $row['b_exp'] == 'pro' ? "<img src= $crown width:10 />" : "" )."
        
            <p>Design: ".$row['b_niv1']." / 10 </p>
            <p>Intuitivität: ".$row['b_niv2']." / 10 </p>
            <p>Vielseitigkeit: ".$row['b_niv3']." / 10 </p>
            <p>Mehrwert: ".$row['b_niv4']." / 10 </p>
            <p>Einzigartigkeit: ".$row['b_niv5']." / 10 </p>
            <p>Gesamteindruck: ".$row['b_nivg']." / 10 </p>
            <p>".$row['b_pro']."<p>
            <p>".$row['b_con']."</p>
            <p>".$row['b_kommentar']."</p>
            <p>".$row['b_datum']."</p>
            <br>
            <br>
        </div>"; 
            
        }
    }
    ?>
                
    
</div>


    
    
    <footer>
                <?php include '../Include/footer.php';?>
            </footer>
    </body>
</html> '''
```

Comment: Change your sort form to GET. Then, if you want to keep the `id`, then just add a hidden input named `id` to the form and populate that inputs value with the id. That would make it be submitted along with the sort form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change your html form like this and to fetch sort value in from get request instead of post

```
 <form action="f_toolseite.php" method="get">
    <input type = "hidden" name = "name" value = "<?= $_GET['name'] ?>" />
    <input type = "hidden" name = "id" value = "<?= $_GET['id'] ?>" />
  <select name="sort">
     <option value="" selected="selected">Nach den neusten Bewertungen geordnet</option>
     <option value="b_nivg ASC">Am besten bewertet</option>
     <option value="b_nivg DESC">Am schlechtesten bewertet</option>
  </select>
  <input name="search" type="submit" value="Ordnen"/>
```